# AngularJS Download Image and Show To HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, web-services, download

I'm trying to implement the feature "Image Profile".
I use https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload to upload the image to webservice server (java) and now i want to get the image to display on user profile page.

In the webservice server, I wrote the method:

```
@GET
@Path("/downloadFile")
@Produces("application/octet-stream")
public Response downloadFile(@FormParam("documentId") long documentId) {
    AssessmentDocument doc = this.documentRepository.findOne(documentId);
    File file = new File(doc.getDocumentPath() + doc.getDocumentName());
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + doc.getDocumentName() + "\"");
    return response.build();
}
```

and in the Angular Service, I wrote the function to call service download:

```
    /**
     *  download file
     * @param user
     * @returns {*}
     */
    this.downloadFilePromise = function (fileId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'},
            url: '.../downloadFile?documentId=' + fileId
        }).success(function (data, status) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            deferred.reject(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Data is returned successfully but I don't know how to process with data returned from server to display to HTML

Help is appreciated.

Many Thanks,